# HashMap.get() works in one snippet and does not work on another one why?

Tags: java, string, hashmap, char

I have a hashmap like the below,

```
static Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {
    {
    put("**", 15); //11 to 19 and 21 to 26
    put("*0", 2); // 1 and 2
    put("*1", 2);
    put("*2", 2);
    put("*3", 2);
    put("*4", 2);
    put("*5", 2);
    put("*6", 2);   
    put("*7", 1);  //1
    put("*8", 1); 
    put("*9", 1); 
    put("1*", 9); //1 to 9
    put("2*", 6); //1 to 6    
}};
```

And I'm trying to get the value corresponding to "2*" from above map like,

**Approach 1**

```
String string = "2*";
char[] ch = string.toCharArray();
map.getOrDefault(ch[0]+ch[1], 0);   //returns 0
```

**Approach 2**

```
String string = "2*";
char[] ch = string.toCharArray();
map.getOrDefault(String.valueOf(ch[0])+String.valueOf(ch[1]), 0);  //returns 6
```

The first snippet returns '0' always whereas the second one could return the correct value. I didn't understand how. Can someone enlighten me on this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following case.

```
String string = "2*";
char[] ch = string.toCharArray();
map.getOrDefault(ch[0]+ch[1], 0);
```

You are adding `ch[0]` + `ch[1]`.  Characters add as integers and that is what you
are trying to get.  The integer sum of `2` and `*`.

You can turn the sum into character concatentation by doing the following:

```
System.out.println(map.getOrDefault(""+ch[0]+ch[1], 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because the values you are getting from the char array are still considered int values, and because of this, you are searching for those char values in the map, which there are none. In the second example, you are explicitly telling your map to get the string representation of those chars, which are in your map.